# $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z} H_* $ is a homology theory

Tags: homology-cohomology, tensor-products

**Problem:** Given is a homology theory $H_*$ with values in $\mathbb{Z}$-Modules. Show, that $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z} H_* $ is also a homology theory with values in $\mathbb{Q}$-Modules.

**Source:** Wolfgang Lück- Algebraic Topology. Homology and manifolds (German). I use it to self study. We start off by defining homology theory (before doing simplicial/singular homology) and deduce some implications from there (mayer-vietoris etc.)

I am particularly confused on the tensor product, given I am not very experienced with it.
To show that $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z} H_* $ is a homology theory, one of the things we have to show is that there is a long exact sequence for every pair $(X,A)$:
\begin{align*}
    \cdots \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\otimes H_n(A) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\otimes H_n(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\otimes H_n(X,A) \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{Q}\otimes H_{n-1}(A) \rightarrow \cdots
\end{align*}

**My arguments:**
We show that for every exact $A\xrightarrow{f} B\xrightarrow{g} C$ we also have an exact $\mathbb{Q}\otimes A\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id} \times f} \mathbb{Q}\otimes B\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id} \times g}\mathbb{Q}\otimes C$, where $A,B,C$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

$\mathrm{Im}(\mathrm{id} \times f) \subset \mathrm{Ker}(\mathrm{id} \times g)$:

Let $\sum_i q_i \otimes a_i \in \mathbb{Q}\otimes A$. Then $(\mathrm{id} \times g)(\mathrm{id} \times f)(\sum_i q_i \otimes a_i) = \sum_i q_i \otimes g(f(a_i))=\sum_i q_i \otimes 0=0$

$\mathrm{Ker}(\mathrm{id} \times g) \subset \mathrm{Im}(\mathrm{id} \times f)$:

Let $0=(\mathrm{id} \times g)(\sum_i q_i \otimes b_i)=\sum_i q_i \otimes g(b_i).$

**Question:** How can I argue now that $g(b_i) =0?$

**Edit question:** how can we prove that the LES is exact?

**Progress:** Let $0=\sum_i \frac{p_i}{q_i}  \otimes g(b_i)$. We multiply by $Q=q_1\cdot \dots \cdot q_n$ to get $0= 1 \otimes \sum_i \frac{Q p_i}{q_i} g(b_i)$. Next I will try thinking about universal properties and exactness.

Comment: The abelian group $\mathbb{Q}$ is flat, meaning that the operation $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} -$ is exact. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221592/how-to-prove-that-mathbb-q-is-flat-as-a-mathbb-z-module and the places it points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not used yet that you are tensoring with the rationals, rather than an arbitrary ring. So try rewriting your equation with fractions and getting rid of the denominators, so that you can use properties of the maps over the integers.

This is a special case of the fact that localization is exact, ie tensoring with a ring which is just "the original ring with some elements inverted".

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I did any homology, but I do not think that $g(b)$ is always zero when $id \otimes g(q \otimes b)$ is zero. I think it is true for free $\mathbb{Z}$ modules, but not in general:

Take for example $A=\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}$ and consider $g=id$. Then you can check that $id\otimes g(1\otimes 1)=1\otimes 1=\frac{1}{2}\otimes 2=0$, but $g(1)=1 \neq 0$. If you multiply $\mathbb{Q}$ by any module with torsion, you loose some information. In case of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2Z}$, tensoring it with $\mathbb{Q}$ gives you $0$.

In general, proving that a certain tensor product is exact can be rather difficult to do, which is why homological algebra is a quite complicated topic. Hopefully someone here can provide a more complete solution.